# How to add gradle into my alpine base docker image

Tags: java, docker, gradle, alpine-linux

I create docker file using alpine base image and built the image. That image contains java:11 and maven. **I want to include gradle also. How do i do it?**

This is the docker file  get also from Stackoverflow.

```
from alpine:3.10

run apk --no-cache add openjdk11 --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community
run apk add bash vim curl wget jq docker git tar unzip bash-completion ca-certificates
run cd /opt && curl -sSl http://mirror.vorboss.net/apache/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz | tar -xz



env PATH "$PATH:/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin"
entrypoint ["/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: Perhaps just install the package? https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=gradle&branch=v3.12

Comment: Gradle is an anti-pattern -- you shouldn't use it at all because it's the opposite of good. Use Maven instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just stole from [here](https://github.com/hipposareevil/alpine-gradle/blob/master/Dockerfile):

```
FROM alpine:3.10

ENV GRADLE_VERSION 3.2

RUN apk --no-cache add openjdk11 --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community
RUN apk add bash vim curl wget jq docker git tar unzip bash-completion ca-certificates
RUN cd /opt && curl -sSl http://mirror.vorboss.net/apache/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz | tar -xz

RUN apk -U add --no-cache curl; \
    curl https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}-bin.zip > gradle.zip; \
    unzip gradle.zip; \
    rm gradle.zip; \
    apk del curl; \
    apk update && apk add --no-cache libstdc++ && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

ENV PATH "$PATH:/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:/gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}/bin/"
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Simpler version just using the current latest Alpine, which also has packages for Maven 3.6.3 and a much more recent Gradle than above.  You can toy around with the versions, of course.

```
FROM alpine:3.12.3

RUN apk --no-cache add openjdk11 --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community
RUN apk add bash vim curl wget jq docker git tar unzip bash-completion ca-certificates gradle maven

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```